# Rounding error in qgis point sampling tool

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm not sure if this is a bug or of it is due to the implementation. I am using a raster that has values greater than 1,000,000 and Qgis displays these numbers in a scientific notation.  For instance, 1,101,702 gets displayed as 1.1017e+06 in the information dialogue.  I know that the raster stores this number correctly, because I polygonized it and the polygon got the correct identifier of 1101702.  But when I run the point sampling tool on the same area, the point gets marked as 1101700.  Does anyone know why this is?  And is there a simple way to fix this issue?

If not, can anyone recommend a way to script a simple point sampling tool that I can include in my data processing scripts?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but as far as I know, the point sampling plugin implements QgsRasterLayer::identify http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a4bcb29bba8fc0fca1e0bed41b6a0ee9b

Comment: Do you know if that is any different than the polygonize tool?